# D3.js zoom translateTo issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an issue restoring transform parameters and applying it to D3 view. When I apply previously saved transform parameters to view. Everything looks nice. But as soon as you try to drag or zoom view the view jumps.

Here what I mean:

https://blockchaingraph.org/#ipfs-Qmdv3dEd5YUsiLv8GJ4ZEKYcBwPU6vKosqCXRWvR7LmcuE

After graph loads, try to drag the view and you will see it jumps.

Here's my code:

```
svg = container.append('svg')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '100%')
            .attr('class', 'graphd3-graph')
            .call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', function () {
                var scale = d3.event.transform.k;
                var translate = [d3.event.transform.x, d3.event.transform.y];
                svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + translate[0] + ', ' + translate[1] + ') scale(' + scale + ')');
            }))
            .on('dblclick.zoom', null)
            .append('g')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '100%');
```

.....

```
var c = container.select(".graphd3-graph");
        svg.attr('transform', data.transform);
        d3.zoom().scaleTo(c, tra.k);
        d3.zoom().translateTo(c, tra.x, tra.y);
```

The question is how to properly apply transform on draggable/zoomable D3 view?
d3.zoom().scaleTo() seems to be working, but d3.zoom().translateTo() completely ignored.

I'm using d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js

Comment: put the zoom in a variable, and apply the transformations to this zoom-var, the callback will be called when zoom changes

Comment: btw, you can call `svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)` -- see [transform.toString()](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#transform_toString)

Comment: Thank you rio, that helped:  var zoom = d3.zoom(); .call(zoom.on('zoom', ... ) ..  c.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(tra.x, tra.y).scale(tra.k));

Comment: thanks alien, yes, I found transform.toString() and used it as well

Comment: One more question - Is there a way to apply transform string directly to zoom (zoomIdentity) ? Currently I have to manually parse it to extract x,y and k